# What does the “Haunt this game” button do in bitlife?

Tags: bitlife

There used to be a “haunt this game” button in bit-life but now they removed it. I could not find anything online about it. Does anybody know what it does?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it used to turn your character into an NPC that you could meet in future lives. It's unclear if all users could meet that NPC or only you. The game developers have been secretive about this feature and never explained it.

Comment: Did you see this firsthand?

Comment: I have seen a lot of conflicting info

Comment: It's speculative, the game devs won't confirm it. But there are multiple reports online where players have encountered previously made characters. Since it's not guaranteed you do, you could believe it does nothing. It's fair to assume that they use this feature to feed their database of NPCs, so every game feels different, with lots of different encounters. Rest in Peace deletes it from the database.

Comment: Any idea why it was removed?